# Is there a way if string repeats to return only repeated letters once?

Tags: c

I made code which will for string "aabbcc" return "abc" but in cases when there is more letters like "aaa" it will return "aa" instead of just one.

Here is the code I made.

```
void Ponavljanje(char *s, char *p) {
  int i, j = 0, k = 0, br = 0, m = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(s) - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < strlen(s); j++) {
      if (s[i] == s[j]) {
        br++;
        if (br == 1) {
          p[k++] = s[i];
        }
      }

    }
    br = 0;
  }
  p[k] = '\0';
  puts(p);
}
```

For "112233" output should be "123" or for "11122333" it should be also "123".

Comment: Bad presentation of problem. Did not understand it.

Comment: As an unrelated comment, you are computing `strlen` in every iteration of each loop. This is an anti-pattern that you should learn to avoid. With C strings it is not necessarily even required to calculate `strlen` once: iterate until the terminating NUL byte.

Comment: Will the repeated chars all be together (e.g. `112233`) or can you have (e.g.) `123123`?

Comment: I think, it should work with only one loop: Store and Remember the first character, if next character is the same as before ignore it and continue the loop. If it is a new character store and remember it, and so on.

Comment: input can be anything `123123` but the result string p should have all the repeating characters. but not more than once

Comment: What is about the example `11222113` is the result `1213` or `123`  - that's not clear.

Comment: What about the input `"11113332222"`? Is the expected output `"132"` or `"123"`?

Comment: @Arkku Compilers today are very advanced and it would be silly to say that they can't figure out that the value of strlen(s) here won't change and the value of this call can be  cached in a processor register :)

Comment: @Arkku Anyway, I also think that it is a good practice to think about such things when writing C/C++ code (or, rather, code in general). But you should really only be optimizing things that you know won't be optimized automatically by the compiler/interpreter.

Comment: @wrongway4you What compiler and settings are you using that optimise away the `strlen` calls from this code? I just tried with gcc and clang with `-O3` and `-Os`, none of which remove the `strlen` calls (even with hard-coded strings in `main` calling this function), and in fact I would be extremely surprised if any compiler was able to remove it. Seems that it would not even be permitted since `s` and `p` could alias.

Comment: @pmg the order of numbers doesnt matter

Comment: @Arkku I tried it with `gcc -O3` and found out that it saved the value of `strlen()` to the memory and just loads that value to the register before loop starts when needed. Compiler knows about **all** of the codepaths of your program, and it also probably knows about which optimizations are safe/not-safe to do. Maybe in cases where that string is not known at the compilation time it won't do something like this, but in simpler cases I doubt it won't optimize.

Comment: @wrongway4you Ok, I need to make the function `static` before I can get it to optimise away (in which case clang replaces the entire function with just a `puts` with the output). But in any case I think it's extremely bad practice to write code like that "because the compiler will fix it", especially as in "real" uses the strings are usually not constant at compile time and understanding how optimization works is extremely complex (e.g., do you need to add `restrict` and/or `const` qualifiers to tell the compiler that the strings don't change/alias in a non-trivial situation).

Comment: @wrongway4you And IMO that isn't even about optimization as such (premature or otherwise), but basic understanding of program flow and computational complexity. I've seen a lot of new programmers make the assumption that `strlen` is either like a mathematical function or a different syntax for accessing a pre-computed property of a string. And if you replace `strlen` with a non-standard function, it becomes less and less likely that it will be optimized away, so I would strongly recommend to always assume that code you write will be run like you write it, not like you think it.

Comment: @Arkku You are probably right. Also, saving values you know won't change before the loop is also better in terms of aesthetics/refactoring possibility, because you introduce a local alias for some kind of value, and, if the alias source changes (you use some other function for string length computation, for example), you just need to change your code in one place, instead of many.

Comment: @wrongway4you The `strlen()` cannot easily be optimized away as code writes to `p`, which may affect `s` (as strange as that may seem - they could overlap) - necessitating a true call to `strlen(s)`.  In a stand-alone code, a compiler may see `s`, `p` do not overlap and optimize out the repeated `strlen()` calls. Without `restrict`, a compiler cannot make that optimization - in general.  @Arkku [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891176/is-there-a-way-if-string-repeats-to-return-only-repeated-letters-once/53892043#comment94629335_53891176) is good.

Answer (score 1):

does the work with a complexity O(n)
I suppose programming can give rmg

```
void Ponavljanje(char *s,char *p)
{
  char n[256] = {0};
  int i = 0;

  while (*s) {
    switch (n[(unsigned char) *s]) {
    case 0:
      n[(unsigned char) *s] = 1;
      break;
    case 1:
      p[i++] = *s;
      n[(unsigned char) *s] = 2;
    }    
    s += 1;
  }

  p[i] = 0;

  puts(p);
}
```

Comment: what is `bzero` getting error on that and `*s` in while what that does ?

Comment: Also, I believe (but am not sure) that the OP wants only repeated characters, while this (currently) outputs one of each distinct character in the input, even if it occurs only once.

Comment: @Arkku to be frank I first did `char n[256] = {0};` but I am not sure all the vector is set to 0, can you say me ?

Comment: @Arkku I did the cast to int to avoid gcc warning with option -Wall (-Wchar-subscripts)

Comment: yes i need only repeated characters for example if i have input like "programming" output should be "rgm" so only letters that repeat

Comment: @TihomirRaicevic ah ok, I understood exactly the reverse, I mean programming => progamin

Comment: @TihomirRaicevic is it ok if the result is rmg ?

Comment: @bruno Yes, `char n[256] = { 0 };` initializes the entire array to zero (note, however, that `char n[256] = { 1 };` does _not_ initialize all elements to one, the missing ones will still be zero). And `memset` is the standard library function that you can use to replace `bzero` if you need a non-zero initial value.

Comment: @Arkku than you, near midnight I do not have all my head :-)

Comment: I edit the code to return rmg for programming (hoping is ok for TihomirRaicevic) and removing bzero

Comment: its not working the intended way, it needs to make a `string p` that consists only of repeating characters from `string s` but there should not be repeating characters in `string p`. example for input "iiijjj" it should be "ij"

Comment: @TihomirRaicevic sorry, I fixed that

Comment: damned, so many edits to have the expected result, sorry ... time for me to sleep

Comment: `n[(int) *s]` is _undefined behavior_ (UB), should `*s < 0`.

Comment: oh yes, of course, better to have n[(*s) & 255] or n[(unsigned char) *s]

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid repeated calls to `strlen(s)`.  A weak compiler may not see that `s` is unchanged and call `strlen(s)` many times, each call insuring a cost of `n` operations - quite inefficient. [@arkku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891176/is-there-a-way-if-string-repeats-to-return-only-repeated-letters-once#comment94629335_53891176).<sup>1</sup>   Instead simply stop iterating when the  *null character* detected.
- Initialize a boolean list of flags for all `char` to false.  When a character occurs, set the flag to prevent subsequent usage.  Be careful when indexing that list as `char` can be negative.
- Using a `const char *s` allows for wider allocation and helps a compiler optimization.

Example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

void Ponavljanje(const char *s, char *p) {
  const char *p_original = p;
  bool occurred[CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN + 1] = { 0 }; // all values set to 0 (false)
  while (*s) {
    if (!occurred[*s - CHAR_MIN]) {
      occurred[*s - CHAR_MIN] = true;
      *p++ = *s;
    }
    s++; 
  }
  *p = '\0';
  puts(p_original);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [@wrongway4you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891176/is-there-a-way-if-string-repeats-to-return-only-repeated-letters-once#comment94629490_53891176) comments that many compilers may assume the string did not change and optimize out the repeated `strlen()` call.  A compliant compiler cannot do that though without `restrict` unless it is *known* that in all calls, `s` and `p` do not overlap.  A compiler otherwise needs to assume `p` *may* affect `s` and warrant a repeated `strlen()` call.

Answer (score 0):

While the inner loop checks `br` to only copy the output on the first repetition, the *outer loop* still passes over each repetition in `s` on future iterations. Hence each further occurrence of the same character will run a separate inner loop after `br` has already been reset.

With `aaa` as the input, both the first and the second `a` cause the inner loop to find a repetition, giving you `aa`. In fact, you always get one occurrence fewer of each character in the output than there is in the input, which means it only works for 1 or 2 occurrences in the input (resulting in 0 and 1 occurrences, respectively, in the output).

Comment: can you help me fix it ?

Comment: @TihomirRaicevic Well, hopefully telling you what is wrong in your current implementation helps you understand how to fix it yourself. If you just want someone else to write the code for you, it seems other answers have obliged that (unfortunately).

Comment: can i add if statement to check if the character is alredy in the new string so that it doesnt add it again

Comment: @TihomirRaicevic Yes, you can iterate over `p` to see if you already have that character. Or you can keep track of previously seen characters in a separate array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works regardless of order:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void
repeat(char *s, char *p)
{
    int slen;
    int sidx;
    int pidx;
    int plen;
    int schr;

    slen = strlen(s);
    plen = 0;

    for (sidx = 0; sidx < slen; ++sidx) {
        schr = s[sidx];

        // look for duplicate char
        int dupflg = 0;
        for (pidx = 0;  pidx < plen;  ++pidx) {
            if (p[pidx] == schr) {
                dupflg = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        // skip duplicate chars
        if (dupflg)
            continue;

        p[plen++] = schr;
    }

    p[plen] = 0;

    puts(p);
}

int
main(void)
{
    char p[100];

    repeat("112233",p);
    repeat("123123",p);

    return 0;
}
```

*Note:* As others have mentioned, `strlen` should not be placed in the loop condition clause of the `for` [because the length of `s` is invariant]. Save `strlen(s)` to a separate variable and loop to that limit

---

Here is a different/faster version that uses a histogram so that only a single loop is required:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void
repeat(char *s, char *p)
{
    char dups[256] = { 0 };
    int slen;
    int sidx;
    int pidx;
    int plen;
    int schr;

    slen = strlen(s);

    sidx = 0;
    plen = 0;

    for (sidx = 0; sidx < slen; ++sidx) {
        schr = s[sidx] & 0xFF;

        // look for duplicate char
        if (dups[schr])
            continue;
        dups[schr] = 1;

        p[plen++] = schr;
    }

    p[plen] = 0;

    puts(p);
}

int
main(void)
{
    char p[100];

    repeat("112233",p);
    repeat("123123",p);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> I would suggest iterating until the terminating NUL byte

Okay, here's a full pointer version that is as fast as I know how to make it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void
repeat(char *s, char *p)
{
    char dups[256] = { 0 };
    char *pp;
    int schr;

    pp = p;

    for (schr = *s++;  schr != 0;  schr = *s++) {
        schr &= 0xFF;

        // look for duplicate char
        if (dups[schr])
            continue;
        dups[schr] = 1;

        *pp++ = schr;
    }

    *pp = 0;

    puts(p);
}

int
main(void)
{
    char p[100];

    repeat("112233",p);
    repeat("123123",p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why so complicated and slow ? :-)

Comment: @bruno Like I've said [to you] before: _baby steps_. Show the most straightforward algorithm first (i.e. fix OP's algorithm with minimal changes). Then, add a more advanced one afterwards

Comment: I made the same error, this is not the expected result, he wants to get _only_ the repeated characters

Comment: re. `strlen`, I would suggest iterating until the terminating NUL byte (e.g., simply `s[sidx]` as the `for` loop condition). Granted, the OP may not be familiar with this approach, so I understand the use of `strlen` here, but I think it's necessary to learn if working with C strings (@TihomirRaicevic).

Comment: @Arkku Yes--of course _I_ would :-). But, I'm trying to write to a/the level that OP can best understand. Note OP's comment to me about needing a fix of his code (vs random code), but [arguably] my first example [as I mentioned] _was_ a fix to _his_ code. On another question, I once coded `for (int chr = *str++;  chr != 0;  chr = *str++)` and that OP complained about _not_ understanding it [_or_ pointer iteration]. I did an additional example _without_ pointer iteration [with a link and admonishment on pointers]. Here, I'll add another that is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove the successive double letters, then this function would be sufficient, and the examples given in the question would fit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Ponavljanje(char *s,char *p)
{
  char dd = '\0';
  char *r;
  if(s == NULL || p == NULL)
    return;
  r = p;
  while(*s){
    if(*s != dd){
      *r = *s;
      dd = *s;
      r++;
    }
    s++;
  }
  *r = '\0';
  puts(p);
}
int main(void)
{
  char s[20] = "1111332222";
  char p[20];
  Ponavljanje(s,p);
}
```

Comment: only the consecutive characters are simplified in that solution, this is not the goal

Comment: Do you mean e.g. "111222333111" results in "123" only? - That is definitely not declared in the examples of the Q.

Comment: yes, and "121 "must give "1", the examples given initially were misleading. I learned that with the remarks

Comment: @bruno: If so, I will remove this answer, should I?

Comment: you and only you decide :-)

Comment: I'll keep it but comment it in the headline... just a moment.

Comment: It shows, if it still needed, the importance of properly posing a problem